# Azure DevOps Pipeline run only on specific tag

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline that I want to only run when a specific tag is pushed to the repo, but for some reason it always runs on every commit.

My `azure-pipelines.yml` has the trigger setup like this:

```yaml
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - mytag.*
```

I also tried excluding all branches:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - "*"
  tags:
    include:
      - mytag.*
```

It seems like it makes no difference what the `trigger` is set as, it just always runs on every commit.

How do I make it run only when I push a tag?

Comment: Is the trigger on the file set the same across all branches?

Comment: @Matt While setting this up, I have been doing everything on an `azure-pipeline` branch. So, there is no `azure-pipelines.yml` on any other branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried what you wrote and it seems to be working:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - '*'
  tags:
    include:
    - v2.*
    exclude:
    - v2.0

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/tags/v2.*
    exclude:
      - 'refs/tags/v2.0'
      - '*'
```

So for this configuration when I make a commit, the build is not triggered. Only when I push a tag the build runs. It picks up last commit, but this this is clearly triggered by tag.

[image]

Here for instance you have another build which was triggered by `Test commit`

[image]

Comment: So, I hadn't really noticed how it says what caused the build trigger (like in your first screenshot). It turns out my builds were actually being triggered by pull-requests. I was able to fix my problem using `pr` instead of `trigger`. It was happening on every commit because I had an open PR for that branch. I find it extremely strange that this is the default functionality though.

Comment: It actually a common thing that you need to repeat settings for both `trigger` and `pr`. I edited my answer to include this. If you could accept my answer or add your own it take down this issue from the radar of other SO users as it will be marked as solved. I'm happy that my answer helped you find out root cause.